# How to sort value by a column "A", preserving order of second column "B" in case of a tie?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe `df` with the columns - `A` [timeseries], `B` [String].

I want to sort the dataframe about column `A` in ascending order(oldest date first); and incase we have a tie for a certain date between two values of `B`, the order of values in `B` should be based on their original order in column B. For example for date 01/01/2022, there are two values in B - `XYZ`, `ABC`. Then, in the sorted dataframe, for 01/01/2022 the first value should be `XYZ` followed by `ABC`.

What I tried?

I tried several ways to get it working, the most close I have come up is with the following -

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['2022-01-01', '2022-01-01', '2022-01-02', '2022-01-03'], 'B': ['lul', 'foo', 'baz', 'qux'], 'X': [1, 1, 2, 2]})

df = df.sort_values(by = ['A','B'], key=lambda x: pd.factorize(x)[0])

display(df)
```

This seem to be working for my example, however, when I tried on my real dataframe, I saw dates not being in the right order ie ascending.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [stable sorting method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Stability) by using `kind='stable'` (or `kind='mergesort'`) in [`sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html):

```
out = df.sort_values(by='A', kind='stable')
```

Output:

```
            A    B  X
0  2022-01-01  lul  1
1  2022-01-01  foo  1
2  2022-01-02  baz  2
3  2022-01-03  qux  2
```

Comment: Sweet. I went through the docs and it seems reasonable. I also tried on the dummy dataset myself and it seems to be working there also. Let me try your suggested method on the real dataset and hopefully it should work there.